# How to port / sync my Windows Terminal settings between computers?

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

I spent quite some time in Windows Terminal to set up my preferences and color themes. What's a good way to port / sync these settings to other computers?

I guess there are 3 tiers of solutions:

**Level 1**: Know I'm about to switch to a new computer or reinstall Windows, thinking how to port my settings.

**Level 2**: No plan to change computers for now, but want to ensure I won't lose my settings if case of disaster.

**Level 3**: Have multiple computers and want the settings to be in sync, e.g. if I change a setting on one computer, the other computer will get it automatically.

All suggestions are welcome, no matter which level!

Comment: Just copy the .json file, however, this synchronization must be done manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Settings, click the "Open JSON file" on the bottom left corner, then copy the json content to somewhere else as a backup. On your new computer, paste it back to restore your settings.

Whenever you make an important change to your settings, remember to update the backup.

---

(not recommended)
You can also use a symlink to make settings.json point to a file in your OneDrive. If set correctly, it may have 2 benefits:

1. When you make a change to the settings, it's auto saved in OneDrive, so you don't need to remember to backup manually.
2. If you have multiple PCs, their settings can be auto mirrored, assuming they all installed the same shells and all shells are installed at the same path. (can be seen in Settings > Profiles > any_profile > Command line)

Caveat:
Windows Terminal may sometimes decide to update settings.json in a "delete-and-recreate-with-updated-content" fashion, which breaks the link without you knowing it. You may re-install Windows then find out the version in your OneDrive hasn't been updating since last year. I have tried hard link and it happened to me. There's a blogpost in the comment section that used soft link, I haven't tried, but in theory the same issue can happen.

Comment: What was unreliable about it? It seemed to have worked fine for me. Could you re-add the instructions with caveats?

Comment: If anyone still wants to go this route, here is a blog post (not mine) that shows the process: https://tsull360.wordpress.com/2020/06/17/synchronize-microsoft-windows-terminal-settings-customizations/

Answer (score 1):

you can also use https://www.chezmoi.io/ for monitoring your files across multiple devices.
It uses Git and tracks the changes for you. However, you might need to check regularly if changes occur. (while OneDrive can do it automatically).